# Generating nuget package using .csproj cause wrong version number

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-assembly

Currently I'm creating a nuget package using a *.csproj and a nuspec file. In the nuspec file I'm declaring the assembly/package version like this:

```
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    ...
  </metadata>
</package >
```

In the assembly the version is declared like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("6.0.0")]
```

The problem is, that when I create the package using `nuget pack xxx.csproj`,
it creates a package with the version `6.0.0.0` instead of `6.0.0`. This makes a problem when installing the assembly using nuget, because visual studio is searching in `package/.../6.0.0` for the assembly, but it is stored in `packages/.../6.0.0`.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet uses other attribute to generate the version replaced in $version$:

[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("6.0.0")]

As said in [how to version assemblies destined for Nuget](https://codingforsmarties.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/how-to-version-assemblies-destined-for-nuget/) NuGet uses this attribute because nothing else seems to care about it :) the AssemblyInformationalVersion attribute is a literal one that can be used for [semantic versions](http://semver.org/)

Comment: Why does nuget replace it in `$id$` and not in `$version$`?

Comment: Sorry, it is a mistake, is $version$ not $id$

Comment: Ok, creating the package seems to work, but why does `msbuild` tries to find the assembly under `.6.0.0.0\lib\net451\` and not under `.6.0.0\lib\net451\`? I'm restoring it using `nuget restore ...sln`. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: NET and Msbuild uses AssemblyVersion attribute to link assemblies. AssemblyFileVersion is just for informational purposes about your builds and if you use AssemblyInformationalVersion for NuGet semantic versions, you should keep the same AssemblyVersion attribute "6.0.0.0" while there are not breaking changes in your lib API and change only AssemblyInformationalVersion minor and build numbers. I'll elaborate it a little in my answer, For now you can read the "real solution" paragraph in the article I have referenced.